# Need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-debug

I have a Ruby on Rails application with Ruby 1.9.3p327 and Rails 3.2.11. I'm trying to use the Ruby-debugger plug-in for Sublime Text. I installed the "debugger" gem. There is no "ruby-debug19" gem in my project. Here is a snippet from my Gemfile.

```
group :development do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

My Gemfile.lock has:

```
debugger (1.6.1)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.2.3)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)
```

When I try to start Webrick,

```
rails s -e development --debugger
```

an error is printed:

```
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
```

I read that this issue is caused by the "ruby-debug" gem, and the solution is to use the "debugger" gem instead, but it's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Silly question - have you installed the gem or just added it to your gemfile?

Comment: If not then run either 'gem install ruby-debug', or 'bundle install' to install all gems in your gemfile

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Mark the debugger gem is installed. 
If I run "gem list -l" I can see it into the list:

Comment: @sawa My question is: why Ruby ask me for "ruby-debug" gem even If I have installed the "debugger gem" according to the Ruby and Rails versions?

Comment: @yuri what output does gem install ruby-debug give you?

Comment: SOLVED: Was my fault. I run "build install --with development" and It works in order to use debugger gem. My ignorance, sorry

Answer (score 0):

@Mark

```
Fetching: hashie-3.5.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed hashie-3.5.7
Fetching: powerbar-1.0.18.gem (100%)
Successfully installed powerbar-1.0.18
Fetching: minitar-0.6.1.gem (100%)
The `minitar` executable is no longer bundled with `minitar`. If you are
expecting this executable, make sure you also install `minitar-cli`.
Successfully installed minitar-0.6.1
Fetching: minitar-cli-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitar-cli-0.6.1
Fetching: archive-tar-minitar-0.6.1.gem (100%)
'archive-tar-minitar' has been deprecated; just install 'minitar'.
Successfully installed archive-tar-minitar-0.6.1
Fetching: ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ruby_core_source-0.1.5
Fetching: linecache19-0.5.12.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed linecache19-0.5.12
Fetching: ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25
Fetching: ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem (100%)
ruby-debug19's executable "rdebug" conflicts with debugger
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
```

This is the gem install ruby-debug19 output

I've also added

```
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug'
end
```

to my Gemfile then run:

```
bundle install
```

Unfortunately when I run:

```
rails s -e development --debugger
```

same error occurs

```
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
```